# Unit test a date function

Tags: testing, qunit

I need to create a unit test for the following function:

```js
export default date => {
  const dateInMs = new Date(date).getTime(); // UTC date
  const clientDate = new Date();
  // timezone offset is in minutes therefore it is being converted to milliseconds
  const offset = clientDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
  return new Date(dateInMs - offset).toISOString();
};
```

I know I should pass the test a date in the following format

```js
2017-07-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

Can someone provide some guidance as to how to write a simple test with this information.

Comment: That, btw, is not a safe way to do time zone conversions. The time zone offset will be different depending on the date in question. For example, right now I'm in Pacific Daylight Time which is -0700 but on `2017-03-01` I was in Pacific Standard Time which is -0800. If you put in `2017-03-01T00:00:00+00:00` should it use the offset now? Or the offset on `2017-03-01`? If it's supposed to use the offset now, the test result will change later in the year (if you're in a time zone that has daylight savings time). That's something to test and discuss with the developers.

Comment: I think the best way would be to use offset now.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What isn't working? Without that, it seems like you're just asking us to write a test for you...